# How to create a close button for success message?

Tags: html, css

I can't create a close button for the message that should appear when I click on submit. I created the button but it didn't work to hide the message.

Here is my code:

```css
body {
         background: #1488EA;
          }

       #card {
         position: relative;
         top: 110px;
         width: 320px;
         display: block;
         margin: auto;
         text-align: center;
         font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
            }

        #upper-side {
         padding: 2em;
         background-color:  #3CB371;
         display: block;
         color: #fff;
         border-top-right-radius: 8px;
         border-top-left-radius: 8px;
        }

        #checkmark {
         font-weight: lighter;
         fill: #fff;
         margin: -3.5em auto auto 20px;
        }

      #status {
        font-weight: lighter;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin-top: -.2em;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        }

        #lower-side {
        padding: 2em 2em 5em 2em;
        background: #F0F0F0;
        display: block;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
                   }

        #message {
        margin-top: -.5em;
        color: #757575;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
                  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html> 
     <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
     </head>
   

    <div id='card' class="animated fadeIn">
     <div id='upper-side'>
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
      <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
      <svg version="1.1" id="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">
        <path d="M131.583,92.152l-0.026-0.041c-0.713-1.118-2.197-1.447-3.316-0.734l-31.782,20.257l-4.74-12.65
 c-0.483-1.29-1.882-1.958-3.124-1.493l-0.045,0.017c-1.242,0.465-1.857,1.888-1.374,3.178l5.763,15.382
 c0.131,0.351,0.334,0.65,0.579,0.898c0.028,0.029,0.06,0.052,0.089,0.08c0.08,0.073,0.159,0.147,0.246,0.209
 c0.071,0.051,0.147,0.091,0.222,0.133c0.058,0.033,0.115,0.069,0.175,0.097c0.081,0.037,0.165,0.063,0.249,0.091
 c0.065,0.022,0.128,0.047,0.195,0.063c0.079,0.019,0.159,0.026,0.239,0.037c0.074,0.01,0.147,0.024,0.221,0.027
 c0.097,0.004,0.194-0.006,0.292-0.014c0.055-0.005,0.109-0.003,0.163-0.012c0.323-0.048,0.641-0.16,0.933-0.346l34.305-21.865
 C131.967,94.755,132.296,93.271,131.583,92.152z" />
        <circle fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="109.486" cy="104.353" r="32.53" />
      </svg>
      <h3 id='status'>
      Success
      </h3>
     </div>
    <div id='lower-side'>
    <p id='message'>
      Thank you for your interest in Neotic.
    </p>
    <div>
    <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
    </div>
    </div>

    </html>
```

The current close button doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like nothing more than a link to the top of the page. What makes you think it should close anything?

Comment: i am sorry maybe my question seems trivial but i am really new .. 
<a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
at href i should add the link right ? 
please i need your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add this code to the button

```
onclick="$('#card').hide();"
```

Answer (score 1):

It can work with jquery

```
$(".ui-btn").on("click",function(){
   $("#card").css("display","none");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right" onclick="document.getElementById('card').style.display= 'none'">Close</a>
```

So this will basicly aim the `card` div which is your message and it will hide it.

Just replace the original link by this one.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have jQuery loaded, here is on solution that works to close the message.

First I have wrapped the content you want to close in another div

```
  <div id="messageContainer">

   <div id='upper-side'>
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg version="1.1" id="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">
      <path d="M131.583,92.152l-0.026-0.041c-0.713-1.118-2.197-1.447-3.316-0.734l-31.782,20.257l-4.74-12.65
  c-0.483-1.29-1.882-1.958-3.124-1.493l-0.045,0.017c-1.242,0.465-1.857,1.888-1.374,3.178l5.763,15.382
  c0.131,0.351,0.334,0.65,0.579,0.898c0.028,0.029,0.06,0.052,0.089,0.08c0.08,0.073,0.159,0.147,0.246,0.209
  c0.071,0.051,0.147,0.091,0.222,0.133c0.058,0.033,0.115,0.069,0.175,0.097c0.081,0.037,0.165,0.063,0.249,0.091
  c0.065,0.022,0.128,0.047,0.195,0.063c0.079,0.019,0.159,0.026,0.239,0.037c0.074,0.01,0.147,0.024,0.221,0.027
  c0.097,0.004,0.194-0.006,0.292-0.014c0.055-0.005,0.109-0.003,0.163-0.012c0.323-0.048,0.641-0.16,0.933-0.346l34.305-21.865
  C131.967,94.755,132.296,93.271,131.583,92.152z" />
      <circle fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="109.486" cy="104.353" r="32.53" />
    </svg>
    <h3 id='status'>
    Success
    </h3>
   </div>
  <div id='lower-side'>
      <p id='message'>
        Thank you for your interest in Neotic.
      </p>

      <a id="closeBtn" href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second create a script to target that container with the .click and .hide() methods.

I have found a few issues with the structure of the html here is the complete file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

  <style>
    body {
      background: #1488EA;
       }

    #card {
      position: relative;
      top: 110px;
      width: 320px;
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
         }

     #upper-side {
      padding: 2em;
      background-color:  #3CB371;
      display: block;
      color: #fff;
      border-top-right-radius: 8px;
      border-top-left-radius: 8px;
     }

     #checkmark {
      font-weight: lighter;
      fill: #fff;
      margin: -3.5em auto auto 20px;
     }

   #status {
     font-weight: lighter;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     letter-spacing: 2px;
     font-size: 1em;
     margin-top: -.2em;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     }

     #lower-side {
     padding: 2em 2em 5em 2em;
     background: #F0F0F0;
     display: block;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
                }

     #message {
     margin-top: -.5em;
     color: #757575;
     letter-spacing: 1px;
               }

  </style>


 </head>


<body>

<h4>This is text in the body of the page</h4>
<div id='card' class="animated fadeIn">

<div id="messageContainer">

   <div id='upper-side'>
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg version="1.1" id="checkmark" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" xml:space="preserve">
      <path d="M131.583,92.152l-0.026-0.041c-0.713-1.118-2.197-1.447-3.316-0.734l-31.782,20.257l-4.74-12.65
  c-0.483-1.29-1.882-1.958-3.124-1.493l-0.045,0.017c-1.242,0.465-1.857,1.888-1.374,3.178l5.763,15.382
  c0.131,0.351,0.334,0.65,0.579,0.898c0.028,0.029,0.06,0.052,0.089,0.08c0.08,0.073,0.159,0.147,0.246,0.209
  c0.071,0.051,0.147,0.091,0.222,0.133c0.058,0.033,0.115,0.069,0.175,0.097c0.081,0.037,0.165,0.063,0.249,0.091
  c0.065,0.022,0.128,0.047,0.195,0.063c0.079,0.019,0.159,0.026,0.239,0.037c0.074,0.01,0.147,0.024,0.221,0.027
  c0.097,0.004,0.194-0.006,0.292-0.014c0.055-0.005,0.109-0.003,0.163-0.012c0.323-0.048,0.641-0.16,0.933-0.346l34.305-21.865
  C131.967,94.755,132.296,93.271,131.583,92.152z" />
      <circle fill="none" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="5" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="109.486" cy="104.353" r="32.53" />
    </svg>
    <h3 id='status'>
    Success
    </h3>
   </div>
  <div id='lower-side'>
      <p id='message'>
        Thank you for your interest in Neotic.
      </p>

      <a id="closeBtn" href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("#closeBtn").click (function(){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#messageContainer').hide();
})
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

I also suggest to look into the bootstrap framework, it is well known and it provides really nice classes and methods to handle modals and messages http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals